# How to get Custom Taxonomy ID from the post ID

Tags: custom-taxonomy

In my setup, I have two custom taxonomy called **Regions** & **Sections**.
All the post in site can either be from region taxonomy or from section taxonomy.

At certain point outside the loop I have the post details and I need the taxonomy ID. I don't have the taxonomy name at that point to use get_the_terms function.

Any help will be very appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [`wp_get_post_terms()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_get_post_terms/) which will return all the terms attached to the post, if any. Then, the first term of the array will be able to tell you which taxonomy it belongs to:

```
global $post;

$terms = wp_get_post_terms( $post->ID, array( 'regions', 'sections' ) );

if( ! empty( $terms ) && ! is_wp_error( $terms ) ) {
    $taxonomy = $terms[0]->taxonomy;
}
```

I do not know what your taxonomy slugs are so I guess, you may need to change them to fit your specific setup.

Comment: Slug is same as you did but 
Received following error:           
WP_Error Object
              (
                [errors] => Array
                (
                    [invalid_taxonomy] => Array
                    (
                        [0] => Invalid taxonomy.
                    )

                 )

              [error_data] => Array
              (
               )

           )

Comment: @santosh433 Are both taxonomy **slugs** are the same as seen above? And both are attached the whatever the post type is, correct? WordPress is saying one of the two is invalid ( or both ).

Comment: Sorry, my mistake. I can print_r the terms now. Only one last question: why have you set the index of $terms array to 0.

Comment: @santosh433 In your original question, you said that each post can either be part of 1 taxonomy or the other taxonomy. This means that all the terms in the array ( which _may_ be multiple terms for all I know ) should have the same taxonomy, `regions` or `sections` so we would only need to check what the first terms taxonomy is to tell us if it's a Section Post or a Region Post.